# Bootstrap for IE8

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to use Bootstrap CSS for the IE-8 browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="col-md-6">Hello</div>
           <div class="col-md-6">Sandy</div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I can't see the two `div`s inside the container next to each other. that would be in adjacent columns, so probably the bootstrap css is not working here.

I am not using media queries, so maybe `respond.js` is not required here.
How can I make it working in IE-8?

Comment: Not sure it "will work" since IE8 came out much much earlier than bootstrap. You may want to check into compatibility libraries if anything.

Comment: @AdamT : I read here : [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support), it works for IE-8

Comment: wondering why the div class = are not enclosed in quotes by 'col-md-6' and col-md-12

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to put your columns into a row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="col-md-6">Hello</div>
       <div class="col-md-6">Sandy</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference. A row also has 12 columns.